# Getting values from a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a multidimesional array in my PHP code ...

```
$wayPoints = $_POST['wayPoints'];
print_r ($wayPoints);
```

that returns

[["1dcb4f6575fbf5ee4ebd542d5981a588",7.67468,44.91085],["7503c3e97935960d0f7abcb6f7ad70f4",7.67614,44.90977]]

I need to get the values at index = 1 and index = 2 in the array:  if I try to get the value

```
7.67468
```

using

```
print_r ($wayPoints[0][1]);
```

I obtain

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1
```

as error

Using

```
print_r ($wayPoints[0]);
```

I obtain

```
[
```

as error

Suggestions?

Comment: that's not an array. it's a string containing a json-encoded array. you need to decode that string, THEN it's just a php array, like any other array.

Comment: you have stings in your array

Comment: it seems that $wayPoints[0] is a string. Are you  sure you should not parse the response first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As definitely your `$_POST['wayPoints']` is a `json_encod`ed string,  try this part of code:

```
// decode your json-string to array
$wayPoints = json_decode($_POST['wayPoints'], true);
// if you want to check what you have:
print_r($wayPoints)
// echo required item:
echo $wayPoints[0][1];
```

More about `json` you can find here, in Documentation, or with google.